# IPMITOOL commands on dell 12th generation controlling the fans

Tags: speedfan

Would be possible to control a particular fan speed in a dell chassis 12th generation? I cannot figure how to do it, just all at once, but let's say I need to lower or increase the Fan5 speed, how do I do that?

Comment: How many pins do these fans have, 3 or 4, it makes a huge difference.

Comment: It has 4 pins Ramhound. This command will change fans to run at 20% for all fans ipmitool -I lanplus  -H 192.168.11.5 -U admin -P pass raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff 0x14 But how do I do that for only a particular fan? Let's say Fan1 or only Fan5?

Answer (score 0):

OK, never mind. Here is the answer if by any chance someone will look for it.

The 4th hex group is controlling the fan ID. Solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).